# float box with jquery not floating

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-float

I'm new to HTML and CSS and I tried to create a floating side bar according to the instruction here. So I added these javascript codes into the html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $sidebar   = $("#sharebox"),
  $window    = $(window),
  offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
  topPadding = 5;

  $window.scroll(function() {
    if ($window.scrollTop() > (offset.top-topPadding)) {
      $sidebar.stop().animate({
      marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
      });
    } else {
      $sidebar.stop().animate({
      marginTop: 0
      });
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

The following codes to CSS:

```
#sharebox       { float: right; margin-left: 800px; background: #FAFAFA;
                  position: absolute; border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
                  -moz-border-radius: 3px;border-radius: 3px; }
#sharebox .wdt  { float: right; clear: left; padding: 5px; }
```

And used the following codes to create the element:

```
<div id="sharebox">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#Search" onclick="return false;"> Search </a></li>
    <li><a href="#Plots" onclick="return false;"> Plots </a></li>
    <li><a href="#Statistics" onclick="return false;"> statistics </a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

But it just is not floating... Could anyone give me some hints?

Thanks.

Comment: Absolute lets you tell it EXACTLY within the parent container to be positioned, using `top` and `left` (or `bottom` and `right`).  Position relative lets the element position/flow naturally, which is the right thing in about 95% of the cases.  If you want it to float, it needs to be relative. http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some error and try, even though I still don't know the reasons, I think the codes above basically works, but just make sure that: 1. you load jquery successfully before the codes (people suggest loading jquery from both google ajax and a local fallback copy); 2. put the floating content in a long enough div for it to have some space to show that it floats :)

Answer (score 0):

In `#sharebox` your `float:right` and `position:absolute` are conflicting.  If you want it to float, remove the position:absolute like so:

```
#sharebox { 
    float: right; 
    margin-left: 800px; 
    background: #FAFAFA;
    border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px; /* gets older safari browsers */
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px; 
}
```

When I tested this, it floated completely right, and slid up and down on scrolling with the jQuery.

Comment: I'm not sure how these things work inside... it actually works for me now after I fotgot about that floating part and work on something else for a while... when I removed the `position:absolute;` statement it actually stopped working.

Comment: Hard to know without seeing your current html/css code.  I know that using what you show in your question, along with my edits, it was working the way I understood you to want it.  Can you edit your question with the revised code you are using, and expand on what you mean by "Stopped Working"?

Comment: I guess you are right about the context dependence. I think why the codes I used didn't work at first was because I put them at the end of the page and that's where they stayed after I removed `position:absolute` like you said. I actually dont know what difference "absolute" and "relative" position makes.